# why is 100% width not 100% in css box modell?

Tags: css

Imagine the following example on that issue:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="col">col1</div>
  <div class="col">col2</div>
  <div class="col">col3</div>
  <div class="col">col4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.col {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

These inner divs should be all in the same line, but they aren't. I mean 4 * 25% = 100%, right?

Codepen to it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmpWQO

Comment: `display: inline-block;` this is your reason

Comment: Read more about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the whitespace and line breaks in your HTML.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.col {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><div class="col">col1</div><div class="col">col2</div><div class="col">col3</div><div class="col">col4</div></div>
```

Comment: Correct! but why should this affect the width while it's not rendered ?

Comment: The whitespaces for example are also inline and have a width. The browser handle these spaces like normal spaces between words. So your calculated width is greater than 100%.

Comment: Thank you dear! It's the first time I know that.

Comment: strangely, that solved my issue. The wihtespace(s) was the problem. If you would like to keep formatting, then `font-size: 0` to `wrapper` does the trick, too.